# Downloading all files with a particular extension from bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am using bitbucket to search for files with the extension `lhs` and containing the text `Configuration` . I am doing this by searching  `ext:lhs "Configuration"`
It gives a list of approx 50 files mentioning `Found matches in 50 files` followed by a list of 50 files in various repositories and the highlighted search keyword.
I want to download all these files. How can I do this? I am unsure if Bitbucket provides any feature like that or if there is a command to achieve this. I am logged into Bitbucket with my organization credentials.
Any hints on how to go about achieving this?

**Objective:**
read the .launch file from each repository and process it which will generate a new file. Push this new file into that repository and automatically open a PR too

Comment: Is this Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org) or something self-hosted? You should be able to use the API to fetch the current version of specific files, but the APIs differ between the two versions.

Comment: @JimRedmond Sorry for the late reply. Yes this is the BitBucket Cloud

Comment: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-source/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-src-commit-path-get